# Windows Phone, how to store data from Json file offline?

Tags: json, windows-phone

I'm new to windows phone  app development.
I need to store data from `json` file in a structured way so that I can use that data when the app is offline.

The `json` file will be updated frequently, so I need to update my database also.

I need to make a  app that should run on windows phone 7, 7.5 and 8.

Comment: What have you tried already? What problems did you face? Do you don't know how to get JSON from web, where to save it, how to load it when it's already saved, how to query it, or something completely different?

Comment: A fast way would be to put it in a string and serialize it using EZ_Iso.dll http://anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is relatively small (I'd say “up to 1-2 MB”), you can store it in a single file in the isolated storage, desterilize it on startup, keep the copy in RAM, and save when it changes. I usually prefer binary XML format produced by data contract serializer for its speed and data size, but you can keep the JSON format, if you want to. BTW, if your data size if less than 100kb, it doesn’t matter which format you’ll choose — choose whatever is easiest to implement for you.

If however your data is larger than 1-2MB, I’m afraid it will take too long to read/write the complete file. If this is your case, you have to somehow split it into smaller pieces, and store them separately in the isolated storage: e.g. in different files, or in different records of the SQLCE database, or some other way that fits your access scenarios.